# How do I create a IAM policy to only allow access to select RDS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I want to create an IAM policy that only allows access to the development and staging RDS instances I have running. This policy will be attached to a user group so that all its users can only read / write to the development and staging instances and not view any details or connect to the production instance.

I have created a test user that is a part of the above mentioned user group for testing out this policy, but it's allowing me to view / alter all db instances I have in RDS right now, including the production instance.

Below is the JSON for IAM policy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:DescribeDBProxyTargetGroups",
                "rds:StartDBCluster",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromS3",
                "rds:ResetDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:DescribeGlobalClusters",
                "rds:ModifyDBProxyEndpoint",
                "rds:PurchaseReservedDBInstancesOffering",
                "rds:CreateDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:ModifyCustomDBEngineVersion",
                "rds:DescribeDBProxyTargets",
                "rds:ModifyDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:DownloadDBLogFilePortion",
                "rds:AddRoleToDBCluster",
                "rds:DescribeReservedDBInstances",
                "rds:CreateDBSnapshot",
                "rds:CreateEventSubscription",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterBacktracks",
                "rds:FailoverDBCluster",
                "rds:AddRoleToDBInstance",
                "rds:ModifyDBProxy",
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeDBProxies",
                "rds:ModifyActivityStream",
                "rds:DescribeDBProxyEndpoints",
                "rds:StartDBInstanceAutomatedBackupsReplication",
                "rds:ModifyEventSubscription",
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshotAttributes",
                "rds:ModifyDBProxyTargetGroup",
                "rds:RebootDBCluster",
                "rds:ModifyDBSnapshot",
                "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                "rds:CreateDBCluster",
                "rds:ApplyPendingMaintenanceAction",
                "rds:BacktrackDBCluster",
                "rds:RemoveRoleFromDBInstance",
                "rds:ModifyDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:FailoverGlobalCluster",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstanceAutomatedBackups",
                "rds:RemoveRoleFromDBCluster",
                "rds:CreateGlobalCluster",
                "rds:DeregisterDBProxyTargets",
                "rds:CreateOptionGroup",
                "rds:CreateDBProxyEndpoint",
                "rds:AddSourceIdentifierToSubscription",
                "rds:CopyDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:ModifyDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:ModifyDBInstance",
                "rds:RegisterDBProxyTargets",
                "rds:ModifyDBClusterSnapshotAttribute",
                "rds:CopyDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:CreateDBClusterEndpoint",
                "rds:StopDBCluster",
                "rds:CreateDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots",
                "rds:DescribeDBSecurityGroups",
                "rds:RemoveFromGlobalCluster",
                "rds:PromoteReadReplica",
                "rds:StartDBInstance",
                "rds:StopActivityStream",
                "rds:RestoreDBClusterFromS3",
                "rds:DescribeValidDBInstanceModifications",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot",
                "rds:ModifyDBClusterEndpoint",
                "rds:ModifyDBCluster",
                "rds:CreateDBClusterSnapshot",
                "rds:CreateDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:ModifyDBSnapshotAttribute",
                "rds:PromoteReadReplicaDBCluster",
                "rds:DescribeOptionGroups",
                "rds:ModifyOptionGroup",
                "rds:RestoreDBClusterFromSnapshot",
                "rds:DescribeDBSubnetGroups",
                "rds:StartActivityStream",
                "rds:DescribePendingMaintenanceActions",
                "rds:DescribeDBParameterGroups",
                "rds:StopDBInstanceAutomatedBackupsReplication",
                "rds:RemoveSourceIdentifierFromSubscription",
                "rds:RevokeDBSecurityGroupIngress",
                "rds:DescribeDBParameters",
                "rds:ModifyCurrentDBClusterCapacity",
                "rds:ResetDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:RestoreDBClusterToPointInTime",
                "rds:CreateCustomDBEngineVersion",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshotAttributes",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterParameters",
                "rds:DescribeEventSubscriptions",
                "rds:CopyDBSnapshot",
                "rds:CopyDBClusterSnapshot",
                "rds:DescribeDBLogFiles",
                "rds:StopDBInstance",
                "rds:CopyOptionGroup",
                "rds:SwitchoverReadReplica",
                "rds:CreateDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:RebootDBInstance",
                "rds:ModifyGlobalCluster",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshots",
                "rds:DescribeOptionGroupOptions",
                "rds:DownloadCompleteDBLogFile",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterEndpoints",
                "rds:CreateDBInstanceReadReplica",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusters",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterParameterGroups",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceToPointInTime"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>:db:development",
                "arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>:db:staging"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusters"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:*:<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>:db:*"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: This policy allows viewing all databases but does not allow modifying all databases. How did you test modification? Is there another policy applied to the users?

Comment: How are your users "connecting" to the databases? Are they authenticating via database credentials, or are they using IAM authentication? Please note that 'logging into' a database is quite different to making calls to the Amazon RDS service.

Comment: @jordanm I created a user called "tester" and made it part of the "Test" user group which has the above mentioned policy attached to it. After logging into aws console as "tester", I was not only able to see all RDS instances, but had the ability to modify all instances (delete, stop, restart, etc.). I'd like all users in the "Test" user group to only be able to view and modify the development and staging instances, and not the production one.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein They are authenticating via database credentials, after which they are able read / write to the database.

Comment: @AdityaMohile did you just see the buttons as visible or did you try to use actually make a modification?

Comment: If the 'tester' can actually modify the production database, then they are receiving these permissions via a different policy than the one you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different elements to consider:

- Ability to 'use' the database
- Ability to 'manage' the database

You have said that users "are authenticating via database credentials", so this access is controlled totally *within* the database and is unrelated to any IAM policies.

Typically, businesses use different AWS Accounts to **separate Production from other environments**. This avoids accidents and ensures that services are deployed and maintained in a reproducible manner (rather than via changes from random people). If you are keeping both Dev & Prod in the same AWS Account, then you will need to be *very* careful about how permissions are granted.

It is not possible to limit the listing of databases. A user either has permission to list *ALL* databases, or *NONE* of the databases.